# Secure WSO2 AS with WSO2 IS

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to configure a WSO2 identity server as security repository for my WSO2 application server. I've read the application server online documentation but I didn't find any reference to this configuration.

Is there any tutorial?

Simple Scenario : I have a Web app configured to use Basic Auth in the web.xml file , and i want to use wso2is as the user store for authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use web service API to integrate with WSO2 Identity Server. WSO2 IS has user-mgt,entitlement APIs.For any user-mgt action and check authorization action,  we can call these APIs from any product. Sorry I couldn't find any tutorial describing this.
Hope following blog post may helpful to you at some point, as it is recommend you to have external LDAP user store. It describes how to connect external LDAP with WSO2 Identity Server.

http://blog.facilelogin.com/2009/06/connecting-wso2-identity-server-20-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the Identity Server for authentication?
Or do you just need a user store?
Or do you need a Token-Service to secure the communication between App-Server and Web-Services?
It is not clear what exactly you want to use th Identity server for. In JBoss for example you also can use authentication with an LDAP, thus you wouldn't need the Identity Server.

Comment: WSO2 Application Server can also do LDAP authentication without the need of WSO2 Identity Server. The Identity Server provides functionality like acting as a IdP for SSO, OpenID etc. I am not clear what the OP asks for exactly.

Comment: If i have installed wso2as and wso2is , Do i need to configure the same LDAP server in both products ? I would like to configure the LDAP server one time in wso2is and then use it as user storage for the other wso2 products, is there any way to do that ?